# How to use SweetAlert before return RedirectToAction by Form Post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

**Model**

```
public class Company{
    [StringLength(30)]  
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string RegisterNo { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="/Controller/Save" style="font-size:13px;">
  <div class="row pb-3">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="position-relative form-group">
          <label class="">Company Name</label> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "30" } })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="position-relative form-group">
          <label class="">Reg No</label> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "15" } })
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button name="submit">Save</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Save(Company CompDet){
     string Name = CompDet.Name;
     string RegNo = CompDet.RegisterNo;

     //then Connect DB and Save DB
     //HOW TO use SweetAlert before, return RedirectToAction
}
```

I'm currently using, `return RedirectToAction` Only.

How to add SweetAlert before RedirectToAction?

Using Ajax Post or Form Post?

Possible that using Ajax & Form Post Together?

**After Saving -> Show Sweetalert success -> return redirectToAction**

I'm still at the learning level. Please Help.

Thank You

Comment: Do edit and limit your question to 1. And you should also include what a "SweetAlert" is-- is it a class? an external api? another controller action?

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio I wan to ask after saving data i wan to show sweetalert SUCCESS then press OK  then return redirectToAction that all...

Comment: `SweetAlert` runs client-side, but `RedirectToAction()` runs server-side. What you want to accomplish is possible but the way you are trying to arrange the pieces will not work.  Typically a scenario like this would have a client-side Ajax call to the POST on the server -- and then SweetAlert success dialog shown in the `done()` or `success()` callback of the Ajax call.  The following post contains full examples of this pattern: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/sweet-alert-with-mvc/